# Does 時 change in pitch in の時に form?

Tags: pitch-accent

At [2m01s](https://youtu.be/6uITdSIZLI8?t=121), the speaker says

> 14歳**の時に**剣術を始めました

I know the usual pitch of 時に is ときに{LHL}; however, here it kind of sounds like the speaker is saying noTOkini のときに{LHLL}. Is there something going on here, or am I just mishearing this?

OJAD also seems to make it Atamadaka, by default (though I know OJAD gets things wrong quite a bit):

> [image]

Comment: She says [ときに]{LHL}.

Comment: 剣術 should be [けんじゅつ]{LHHHH}, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「とき」 is essentially always said as atamadaka **when used as a grammar** element (that means something like "when" in English). [Note that older speakers, or people who are hypercorrecting or religiously following NHK recommendations may still say it odaka.]

> 子供のと＼きに
> 渡したと＼きに

However, **when used as a noun meaning 時間 ("time")**, it is always pronounced as odaka (and following normal odaka rules, that means it will lose its accent before の). This includes when it is modified.

> とき＼と共に
> 流れていくとき＼を感じる
> ときの流れ

Comment: While 子供のと＼きに is completely natural, I think I myself default to 子供のとき＼に.

Comment: 子供のと＼きに sounds to me like a dialect.

Comment: Would その時, as at [7m52s here](https://youtu.be/nQ41Tkj2GRs?t=472), constitute an example of そのとき{LHHL}? It sounds like this is what the speaker is saying, though there's no に after 時.

Comment: @aguijonazo 子供のと＼きに is perfectly standard. Examples in professional voice acting: https://www.immersionkit.com/dictionary?keyword=%E3%80%8C%E5%AD%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%80%8D&sort=shortness || https://www.immersionkit.com/dictionary?keyword=%E3%80%8C%E5%AD%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%AE%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%80%8D&sort=shortness

Comment: @George Yes, that's an instance of the grammaticalised 時. It's not mandatory to use に afterwards (in writing, when に is absent, a comma will often follow this 時) (on the topic of writing, as a sidenote, this とき is often written in kana, as grammar elements / function words / semantically light words tend to be).  || https://bunpro.jp/grammar_points/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D || https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/time-clauses/ || https://old.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/z0jm8a/a/ix9srb0/

Comment: @Dragon_Fang - It doesn't change the fact that it sounds to *me* like a dialect.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. I found [the following](https://okwave.jp/qa/q8357066.html) though it's secondary (bold added).

> **前に修飾語が来た場合（上がるトキ、感じたコト）にはトキ・コト**（トキについてはやや不確か）に限って**頭高型に（も）発音する人もある**ということを、東京生まれのアクセント研究者だった川上蓁という人が書いた本の中で見た記憶があります

---

Other accents of とき

- ときは{LHL}金なり - Here any other accent is odd.

But ときの{LHH} seems to be listed as heiban in [a dictionary](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13171137573) (probably new NHK, which I don't have).